# Взаимодействие с БД

Tags: c++, база-данных, qt

Создаю приложение, которое работает с БД. БД представляет собой данные о школе(ученики, сотрудники школы, классы, родители учеников и т.д.). И вот в процессе разработки возник у меня вопрос... Как лучше работать с БД есть 2 варианта:

1. Это связывать все с базой напрямую к примеру... Если нужно отсортировать таблицу, то пишем запрос к БД, принимаем данные от БД и обновляем таблицу. Точно также поступаем и с добавление удалением, поиском и т.д., т.е. суть заключается в постоянном большом потоке обменов данных с БД.

   #### Пример работы на прямую

   ```
   ... 

   void StaffsForm::updateTableModel(QString &stringQuery)
   {
       model->removeRows(0, model->columnCount());
       QSqlQuery query = dataBase->execS(stringQuery);
       for(size_t row = 0; query.next(); row++)
       {
           for(size_t col = 0; col < model->columnCount() ; col++)
           {
               QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(query.value(col).toString());
               model->setItem(row, col, item);
               //освобождается память в другом месте
           }
       }
   }

   ... 

   void StaffsForm::clickedBtnDel()
   {
       QModelIndexList selectedRows = getSelectedRows();
       if(!selectedRows.size() == 0)
       {
           QMessageBox::StandardButton confirm = FormProperties::Confirm("Действительно хотите удалить сотрудника?");
           if(confirm == QMessageBox::Yes)
           {
                ui->statusbar->showMessage("Удаление из базы данных сотрудника(ов) ");
                for(size_t i = 0; i < (size_t)selectedRows.size(); i++)
                {
                    QString name = selectedRows.at(i).data().toString();
                    ui->statusbar->showMessage(ui->statusbar->currentMessage() + " | " + name);
                    dataBase->execDelete("DELETE FROM staffs WHERE name = '" + name + "'");
                }
                this->updateTableModel(commonQuery);
           }
       } 
       else 
       {
           FormProperties::WarnMessage("Не выделена строка, либо выделена не целиком.");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Можно сделать класс моделей к примеру Сотрудника, в нем хранить данные о сотруднике, потом создать класс в котором будет храниться вектор этих объектов, которые будут заполнены с БД. Ну и уже с ними производить сортировку поиск и т.д.. Но а если уже добавление либо удаление, то понятно дело добавляем либо удаляем данные из/в списке и пишем запрос на добавление либо удаление данных в БД.

   #### Пример модели

   ```
   class Staff : public Models
   {
   private:
       QString name;
       QString number;
       QString address;
       QString personalData;
       QString dateOfBirth;
       QString profession;
       QString predmet;
       Staff(QString &name, QString &number, QString &address, QString &personalData,
             QString &dateOfBirth, QString &profession, QString &predmet);
   public:
       class Builder {
           QString name;
           QString number;
           QString address;
           QString personalData;
           QString dateOfBirth;
           QString profession;
           QString predmet;
       public:
           // setters
           Staff* build();
       };
   // getters
   };
   ```

   #### Пример работы с моделью

   ```
   ...

   void StaffsModel::fillItems()
   {
       QSqlQuery query = dataBase->execS(commonQuery);
       while(query.next())
       {
           Staff *staff = Staff::Builder()
               .setName(query.value(0).toString())
               .setNumber(query.value(1).toString())
               .setAddress(query.value(2).toString())
               .setPersonalData(query.value(3).toString())
               .setDateOfBirth(query.value(4).toString())
               .setPredmet(query.value(5).toString())
               .setProfession(query.value(6).toString())
               .build();
       staffs.append(staff);
       }
   }

   void StaffsModel::updateDataInTable()
   {
       model->removeRows(0, model->columnCount());
       for(size_t row = 0; row < staffs.size(); row++)
       {
           Staff *staff = staffs.at(row);
           model->setItem(row, 0, new QStandardItem(staff->getName()));
           model->setItem(row, 1, new QStandardItem(staff->getNumber()));
           model->setItem(row, 2, new QStandardItem(staff->getAddress()));
           model->setItem(row, 4, new QStandardItem(staff->getPersonalData()));
           model->setItem(row, 4, new QStandardItem(staff->getDateOfBirth()));
           model->setItem(row, 5, new QStandardItem(staff->getPredmet()));
           model->setItem(row, 6, new QStandardItem(staff->getProfession()));
       }
   }

   ...
   ```

Не могу понять как это лучше делать и кой из методов является костыльным, может кто-нибудь подскажут?

Comment: ответ очевидный - в первом случае все просто. Если появится ещё клиент, то все будет работать. Во втором случае мало того, что нужно будет формально сделать всю работу за базу, так ещё и потом решать проблемы синхронизации.

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант предпочтительнее, так как создатели СУБД проделали огромную работу по оптимизации своего движка, и он выполнит поиск, сортировку, выборку гораздо лучше вас. Если боитесь делать большую выборку из таблиц, то выборку можно ограничить предложениями `TOP` или `LIMIT` в зависимости от вашей СУБД, и отобразить только те строки, которые поместятся на экран. А при прокрутке запрашивать дополнительные строки. В моделях Qt для этого есть метод `fetchMore`.

При работе по второму методу вы можете столкнуться с проблемами при одновременном доступе нескольких клиентов. Если они одновременно будут редактировать какую-либо запись в таблице, результат может оказаться неожиданным.